# How to download and upload data from an excel spreadsheet stored on a SharePoint site into a local excel spreadsheet?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, vba, spreadsheet

I am exploring a method to download and upload information from an excel spreadsheet stored on a SharePoint Site from a VB based form in a local excel file. Can you please assist me in understanding the method to do this. I intend to help my technical team with the responses that i receive from the community.

I also wanted to check whether this method will allow multiple users to access the data on the SharePoint Stored excel file and update records in it simultaneously.

in case you have a better solution to achieve this please do also let me know.

thanks.
Kaustav

Comment: Can you clarify a bit on what you're trying to do? What I in particular can offer is a way of triggering automatic uploads to document libraries in SharePoint. That said, if you're trying to automate edits from one workbook to another, that is also technically possible, but I'd need to know before I put more effort in.

Comment: Hi Matt thanks for your response, i currently have a local excel file which has a VB based form within it to enter data. the data that is being entered is saved into a same file however on a different worksheet. the VB form also allows to populate the information back into the form based on the selected unique id. I intend to have a central master file stored in SharePoint which is accessed by the local file for updating and adding new information. the local file then would need also to fetch already existing data based on the unique id selected. I hope this clarifies. thanks.

Comment: Help me understand how the unique ID is incorporated here--are all unique IDs present in the form file in addition to the master file?

Comment: Yes Matt, all the Unique IDs will be present on the form file as well as the Master file.

Comment: I think this would be my last question--is there a need for your master file to feed unique IDs to the form, or will the list of unique IDs be static?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding, New unique ids will be created from the form if the user needs to create a new record in the master file. he will then fill in the data in the form, click on save, and the record will be saved in the master file as new record. However if the user requires to update and existing record which is again differentiated using a Unique id, then the user will enter the existing unique id in the form and the form should fetch the corresponding record from the master and populate the form so that the user can edit and update the record. this record will then be saved.

Comment: Hi any luck with solution?